# How to run a go app continously on an Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, go

Couldn't seem to find a direct answer around here.

I'm not sure if I should run ./myBinary as a Cron process or if I should run "go run myapp.go"

What's an effective way to make sure that it is always running?
Sorry I'm used to Apache and Nginx.

Also what are best practices for deploying a Go app? I want everything (preferably) all served on the same server. Just like how my development environment is like.

I read something else that used S3, but, I really don't want to use S3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the capabilities your init process provides. You're likely running system with either Systemd or Upstart. They've both got really easy descriptions of services and can ensure your app runs with the right privileges, is restarted when anything goes down, and that the output is are handled correctly.

For quick [Upstart description look here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html), your service description is likely to be just:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
setuid the_username_your_app_runs_as
exec /path/to/your/app --options
```

For quick [Systemd description look here](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html), your service is likely to be just:

```
[Unit]
Description=Your service

[Service]
User=the_username_your_app_runs_as
ExecStart=/path/to/your/app --options

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: While using systemd, you can then use journalctl to obtain logs

Comment: Great answer. There's also Supervisor, which I discussed in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30950683/556573

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in an inifiny loop, such as:

```
#! /bin/sh
while true; do
  go run myapp.go
  sleep 2 # Just in case
done
```

Hence, once the app dies due some reason, it will be run again.

You can put it in a script and run it in background using:

```
$ nohup ./my-script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the nohup shell command. What does >/dev/null 2>&1 & mean???

Comment: >/dev/null means "redirect stdout to /dev/null (don't print anything from stdout on screen);
2>&1 means "redirect stderr to stdout (which is /dev/null, so anything from both stdout and stderr will be print on screen);
& means "run in background"

Comment: But what about 2>&1 &???

Also does the .sh script run from the root directory are the base directory?

Comment: You have to put the .sh script in the same location you have myapp.go (or modify the .sh script properly)

Comment: Same as screen solution - this will not survive system reboot. Not sure if that qualifies as "make sure that it is always running".

Answer (score 0):

You may want to go for virtual terminal utility like screen here. Example:

```
screen -S myapp # create screen with name myapp
cd ... # to your app directory
go run myapp.go # or go install and then ./myappfrom go bin dir
Ctrl-a+d # to go out of screen
```

If you want to return to the screen:

```
screen -r myapp
```

EDIT: this solution will persist the process when you go out of terminal, but won't restart it when it'll crash.

Comment: This is much more useful! Thank you!

Comment: This is correct only for some value of "persist". It will survive terminal being closed, but it will not survive server reboot. That doesn't qualify as "persist" usually.

Comment: It also won't restart your app when it crashes, handle logs (capture or rotate them), etc. Running a server via screen is very fragile.