# Equivalent of python's utils.execute() in golang

Tags: python, go

I am newbie to golang and am currently working with binaries in python with utils.execute(). I have to convert the code to golang, what's the equivalent to it in go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check golang [`exec.Command`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command), as in [`os/exec/example_test.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/os/exec/example_test.go#L24-L34)

```
func ExampleCommand() {
    cmd := exec.Command("tr", "a-z", "A-Z")
    cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader("some input")
    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("in all caps: %q\n", out.String())
}
```

First parameter is the command you want to execute, the rest are the parameters.

```
func Command(name string, arg ...string) *Cmd
```

In that same [`os/exec/example_test.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/os/exec/example_test.go), you will find examples on how to read the output, start a command or even do a pipe.

Comment: to run the command with root privileges, in python we give run_as_root=True. Is it same in golang as well?

Comment: @Sagheer you would need for instance a process supervisor (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30950683/6309) or use `su root -c "..."` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30942527/6309)